# Server 16.04 Guest Acct can not access samba share pointing to second HD

Tags: server, mount, samba

I'm new to Ubuntu Server and trying to setup a server with an old machine I had laying around.

So far, so good, except for some reason I can't access samba shares with the guest account if the share is pointing to sdb1 which is mounted to /data. When I create a second identical share pointing to a location on sda1, everything works as expected for the guest account.

sda1 is 40GB mounted to / during installation of server 16.04.
sdb1 is 2TB  mounted to /data via FSTAB entry.

I'm really stuck on this one. The testing I have done leads me to believe it is not a samba problem, but maybe a mounting issue.

Here are my samba entries... identical except for path...

```
[Test1]
   path = /data/test
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes

[Test2]
   path = /home/test
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
```

Both shares are visible from my Win10 client and an IOS app called File Explorer. Click on [Test2] and I'm in with read-only access. But when I click on [Test1] I get prompt for a user ID and Guest will not work.  My admin ID works with both shares as expected.

So to recap, the Guest account can not access the sdb1 via samba shares.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: forgot to mention that permissions are also identical 755 on /data/test and /home/test .  I tried 777 on /data/test but that didn't help.

Comment: Guest accounts are dangerous accounts to have open, why do you want to use guest?

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the permissions on /data

Issue resolved.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.) If you want an up-vote you can ping me after the change,